# Magento install

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I'm trying to move my magento store from local to web server. But I run into a problem,

The install wizzard pops out, I can't figure out why.

What I tryed till now:

- Double checked the database settings - OK.
- Mage.php exists in app folder.
- Deleted files from VAR folder.
- Updated permisions to 777

UPDATE: INFO ABOUT PERMISIONS.

Thank you guys,

Comment: What do you mean by "pops out"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/magento-keeps-invoking-install-script-after-deployment

Comment: Solved it, you can read in the comment's of this post:
[Magento StackExchange][1]


  [1]: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5134/magento-keeps-invoking-install-script-after-deployment

Answer (score 0):

This happens if app/etc/local.xml is missing.

Good luck!

Comment: Now updating them... Will update about the result... Now in progress of changing all the permisions to 777

Answer (score 0):

Change the details of the database in the local.xml according to your server database(host, username, password and database name) and change url of the store in core_config_data.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer